# Receiving POST Request on Server (Spring Framework) from Android Application

Tags: android, spring, post, spring-mvc

I am sending a POST request to a Server from my Android Application. The Server is developed using Spring Framework. The request is received by the server but the parameter that I was sending is null/empty (shown in the log).

The code used to send POST request is:

```
DefaultHttpClient hc=new DefaultHttpClient();  
ResponseHandler <String> res=new BasicResponseHandler();  

String postMessage = "json String";

HttpPost postMethod=new HttpPost("http://ip:port/event/eventlogs/logs");  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);    
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", postMessage));

postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));    
hc.execute(postMethod,res);
```

I have also tried to set HttpParams as follows but it has also failed:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("json", postMessage);
postMethod.setParams(params);
```

The code on Server side that received this request is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/eventlogs/logs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String logs(@ModelAttribute("json") String json) {

    logger.debug("Received POST request:" + json);

    return null;
}
```

The Logger message that I am logging shows:

```
Received POST request:
```

Any ideas what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the RequestParam Annotation and it works for me. Now the code on server is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/eventlogs/logs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String logs(@RequestParam("json") String json) {
logger.debug("Received POST request:" + json);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: And on the client you specify the parameters as the entity of the request. Specifying them as setParams will still not work.

Comment: I have completely same problem. when I do what you said, I am getting  org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required Integer parameter 'channel' is not present. I am sending parameter from android client with basic name valuepair. Can  you help?

Comment: @Emilla is it possible that your parameter can be missed, then mark it as required = false. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3466851/867475

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps Spring isn't converting your `POST` body into a `Model`.  If that is the case, it will not know what the attribute `json` is on your `Model` because there is no `Model`!

Take a look at the [Spring Documentation regarding mapping the request body](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody).

You should be able to use Springs `MessageConverter` implementations to do what you want.  Specifically, take a look at the `FormHttpMessageConverter`, which converts form data to/from a `MultiValueMap<String, String>`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/eventlogs/logs", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String logs(@RequestBody Map<String,String> body) {
    logger.debug("Received POST request:" + body.get("json"));

    return null;
}
```

Adding this line to your xml configuration should enable the `FormHttpMessageConverter` by default:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: Thanks @nicholas.hauschild for your response. I have tried the RequestBody annotation but it returns me the HTTP Error 415 Unsupported media type (http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html). After that I have replaced the RequestBody annotation by RequestParam annotation and it works. Now I am getting the POST request parameters on server.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need add a content-type header from the client. The MessageConverter for JSON registers it self with a couple of content-type it will accept, one is application/json.

If you send with a content-type not handled by any MessageConvert it won't work.

Try adding "Content-type: application/json" as a header.